# SpringBootTest NULL Secondary Dependencies

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, junit4

I am testing a SpringBoot rest controller with JUnit 4 (not 5).
I'm injecting the controller into the test with @Autowired and it is coming in non null so the Spring application context is delivering beans (and I can add it as an autowire on the test and it's non null).
The problem is that all the autowired dependencies on the injected rest controller are null (and an @Value field too), i.e. I get the bean from the context but it hasn't been autowired. Note: I am not manually creating the controller with new.

These are the annotations on the test:

```
@RunWith(SpringRunner.class)
@SpringBootTest(classes = {MyApplication.class})
@ActiveProfiles({"local", "test"})
```

and I am using the following dependencies in the build gradle

```
testImplementation 'junit:junit:4.13.1'
testImplementation 'org.junit.vintage:junit-vintage-engine'
```

Unfortunately I can't post the code. It's a multi project gradle build, but I am not testing across projects. The application is in a package above the package containing the controller.

Comment: What is `MyApplication.class`? Usually it should be a spring boot configuration file with specified set of beans to load. If you want to load all the beans (including services, DAOs, etc) then try running `@SpringBootTest` without parameters at all.

Comment: It's the SpringBoot application class. I've tried SpringBootTest without the argument - doesn't make any difference

Comment: I've tried adding constructor injection to the controller class and add a breakpoint. It gets called before the test runs and the dependencies get injected, but when the test runs it gets a different instance of the controller injected, one with null dependencies.

Comment: Its hard to tell what happens based on this info only... Is it possible that other beans usually injected into the controller are coming from other jar modules and hence are not processed by spring boot test?

Comment: Would @EnableAspectJAutoProxy on the application mess things up?

Answer (score 0):

Yep, this was some aspect oriented programming that was intercepting stuff on the object and preventing the real values from being returned - returning null instead from a proxy.